# Rails Association logic on event and ticket

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, associations

I am writing an event application using ruby on rails and i am stuck on how to do the association effectively: the association is base on the following table User, Event, Ticket. The problem i have right now is the ticket and events, they are two type of tickets: free & paid which also have quantity.

i will be glad if anyone can help me with this association thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the type of the ticket types you should look into [`STI`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html).

Prerequisites:

```
# Gemfile
gem 'active_record_union'
```

It basically goes something like this:

```
class Ticket
end

class FreeTicket < Ticket
  # Free-ticket stuff goes here
end

class PaidTicket < Ticket
  validates :price, presence: true # and other paid-related checks
end
```

I suggest something along these lines for associations:

```
class Event # Also STI
end
class FreeEvent < Event
  has_many :free_tickets
  has_many :users, through: :free_tickets
end
class PaidEvent < Event
  has_many :paid_tickets
  has_many :users, through: :paid_tickets
end
class Ticket
  belongs_to :event
  belongs_to :user
  scope :open, -> { where(user_id: nil) }
  scope :taken, -> { where.not(user_id: nil) }
end
class User
  has_many :free_tickets
  has_many :paid_tickets
  has_many :free_events, through :free_tickets
  has_many :paid_events, through :paid_tickets

  def events
    free_events.union(paid_events)
  end
end
```

This way you can do something like:

```
Event.find(1).tickets.count # => 13
Event.find(1).tickets.open.count # => 10
Event.find(1).tickets.taken.count # => 3
Event.find(1).users.count # => 3
User.find(1).events.count # => 1
User.find(1).free_events.count # => 0
User.find(1).paid_events.count # => 1
```